# StreamStyle can not change the style of some lines which specified by StreamPoints

Tags: plotting

**StreamPoints** will give some specific lines, and I want to change their style by **StreamStyle**, but now it only will change the black part lines style, the **StreamScale** will change the red lines' style, but how to put the arrow in the middle??

```
StreamPlot[{-x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamPoints -> {{{{1, 0}, Red}, {{-1, 0}, Red}, 20}, 0.2, 
Scaled[0.5]}, StreamStyle -> {Black, Arrowheads[{{0.05, .5}}]}, StreamScale -> Full]
```

[image: v]

Answer (score 1):

Change `Red` to `{Arrowheads[{{0.05, .5}}], Red}` to get

[image]